# Rails 5.0 Passing strings or symbols to the middleware builder Deprecation Warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, middleware

`rails 5.0`, `ruby 2.6.4`

I'm upgrading an app to `rails 5.0`.  I'm currently trying to resolve a few Deprecation Warnings.  This is one I'm not finding any help with and I'm not sure where else to look.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing strings or symbols to the middleware builder is deprecated, please change
them to actual class references.  For example:

  "CatchRequestErrors" => CatchRequestErrors
```

I only find "CatchRequestErrors" in two files:

```
app/middleware/catch_request_errors.rb

class CatchRequestErrors
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    begin
      @app.call(env)
    rescue ActionController::BadRequest => error
      ::Rails.logger.warn("WARN: 400 ActionController::BadRequest: #{env['REQUEST_URI']}")
      @html_400_page ||= File.read(::Rails.root.join('public', '400.html'))
      [
          400, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" },
          [ @html_400_page ]
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
config/application.rb

# Middleware that catches the ActionController::BadRequest error, logs it and returns a 400 error page
config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Head, "CatchRequestErrors"
```

I've done a bit of Googling, but have not seen anything that stands out to me as to how to fix this.

Is there a specific syntax for the line in `config/application.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Head, "CatchRequestErrors"`

To

`config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Head, CatchRequestErrors`

Assuming it is properly loaded you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work.  I get an error:  

NameError: uninitialized constant Alumni::Application::CatchRequestErrors

Comment: you may want to try `::CatchRequestErrors`, also make sure that your file is either manually loaded via `require` or properly defined so that Rails' autoloader can find it: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html — for example, Rails expects "MySpace" class to be defined in `app/models/my_space.rb`, `app/*/my_space.rb` where `*` is not one of the default folders, or in `lib/my_space.rb` (amongst others)

Comment: That was it, but I needed to use `require_relative "../app/middleware/catch_request_errors"`  to load the file.  Thanks so much for the reminder to make sure the file was loaded.